# Best discriminatory method for 1d data with a lot of variance

Tags: classification, svm, one-class-classification

I have a problem that I have tried to solve using Support Vector Machines (SVMs) to discriminate 1d series of data between two classes. One of the classes have very specific characteristics and are easily distinguishable from a human perspective, the only drawback is that the other class has data with a lot of variation from data sample to data sample, and it looks like it is not feasible to use this as a class at all. I'm only interested in discriminate between data that is from the class of interest (see image under) and all other "uninteresting" data. Then I tried implementing a one class SVM (OC-SVM), and it looks like it works okey but not as well as I had hoped. Therefore I started looking at alternatives, and came across one-class neural networks and Generative Adversarial Networks (GANs) as a possible solution. The Idea is that since the data points that I want to detect has a certain characteristic (see Image under) then an Adversarial network could preform well. I am very new to the field of neural networks and deep learning, so I wanted to ask the community if I am on to something before diving into it. Feel free to come up with alternative methods as well.

Ps: Unsupervised methods and clustering has not worked well solving this problem because of huge variations in the data.

[Image of data of interest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnmhm.png)

Comment: You're unlikely to get an answer from the community since its all theory. You need to provide practical examples of what you've tried so far for others to help you

Comment: You are mixing a lot of things together that I am afraid they are not being correctly considered. ( GANs for example, I do not see how it gets related to the problem you have described) I kindly suggest to hold on and read the materials step by step with a deep understanding of the concepts, and try them from the simple one to a more complicated one, get the practical result, and then share your concern or bugs here in the community. Best of luck!